# Time Series Stationary Technique

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working with time series data (non-stationary), I have applied `.diff(periods=n)` for differencing the data to eliminate trends and seasonality factors from data.

By using `.diff(periods=n)`, the observation from the previous time step (`t-1`) is subtracted from the current observation (`t`).

Now I want to invert back the differenced data to its original scale, but I am having issues with that. You can find the code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DacBLM6Y6YN5NHlRJdiEInl1WkfZHvrd?usp=sharing#scrollTo=AfMVhOG2SO8l).

My code for differencing:

```
data_diff = df.diff(periods=1)     

data_diff.head(5)
```

My code for inverting the differenced data back to its original scale:

```
cols = df.columns
x = []
for col in cols:
    diff_results = df[col] + data_diff[col].shift(-1)
    x.append(diff_results)
diff_df_inverted = pd.concat(x, axis=1)

diff_df_inverted
```

As you can see from last output in the code, I have successfully inverted my data back to its original scale. However, I do not get the inverted data for row 1. It inverts and shifts the values up a row. My question is, why? What am I missing?

thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
diff_results = df[col] + data_diff[col].shift(-1)
```

`data_diff` starts from the second row and that is the reason it appears as it could be shifted up.
The reason for this is because you use `.shift(-1)`.

An easy solution would be using [df.cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html#pandas-dataframe-cumsum) as it is the exact opposite of `df.diff()`.

The only thing you have to do is get the first row to replace the `NaN` values from your `data_diff` dataframe. You need to do this because it is the original row that every other row would be added to. After that, you call `data_diff.cumsum()` and now you have the original data.

Here is the detailed code.

```py
data_diff.iloc[0]=df.iloc[0]
a = data_diff.cumsum()
```

Comment: Thank you @H. pap . I get that .cumsum() will cumulatively add the values in each row. However, I do I use it to add the values on each column between two data frames (df and data_diff) ?